# Decode continuation frame in websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

How do you decode a continuation frame in websocket? Can someone please give me a useful insights into this? Decoding a continuation frame as text frame results in error.

I'm sending a large text-string to the server and I can manage to decode only the first incoming text frame and fails after that.

Here is a simple function in nodejs that handles the text frame decoding -

```
function decodeWS(data)
{
    var dl = data[1] & 127;
    var ifm = 2;
    if (dl == 126) 
    {
        ifm = 4;
    } else if (dl == 127) 
    {
        ifm = 10;
    }
    var i = ifm + 4;
    var masks = data.slice(ifm,i);
    var index = 0;
    var output = "";
    var l=data.length;
    while (i < l) 
    {
        output += String.fromCharCode(data[i++] ^ masks[index++ % 4]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how decoding "fails" please?  What data do you send?  I presume you do manage to decode messages but they don't contain the content you expect?  What are the differences (e.g. length and/or content)?

Comment: @simonc the data type is text. They are sent over to the server as fragmented frame as the data are large in size. So, when the received fragmented frames are run through the decoder function, it gives out some strange looking characters. According to the websocket specification, it states that all the fragmented frames should be concatenated and parsed as websocket frame. For this, I need to extract out the FIN bit to determine the last incoming fragments but I'm not so sure as how to extract that. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6):

Get specific Frame bits

## Fin Bit

```
bool fin = (data[0] & 128) == 128;
```

## OpCode

```
int opCode = data[0] & 15;
```

## IsMasked

```
bool isMasked = (data[1] & 128) == 128;
```

## DataLength

```
int dataLength = data[1] & 127;
```

---

## Websocket frame overview

```
0                   1                   2                   3
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+-------------------------------+
|F|R|R|R| opcode|M| Payload len |    Extended payload length    |
|I|S|S|S|  (4)  |A|     (7)     |             (16/64)           |
|N|V|V|V|       |S|             |   (if payload len==126/127)   |
| |1|2|3|       |K|             |                               |
+-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
|     Extended payload length continued, if payload len == 127  |
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
|                               |Masking-key, if MASK set to 1  |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Masking-key (continued)       |          Payload Data         |
+-------------------------------- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
:                     Payload Data continued ...                :
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
|                     Payload Data continued ...                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

## General Info on how to get specific bits of a byte

*Example: Getting the FIN Bit*

First of all write down the binary representation of the first byte, lets pretend the first bit is `130`, so `1000 0010` in Binary or more understandable Fin bit set and opCode 2 for Binary Data.
If you want the get the most significant bit you need to use the logical AND (&) operator with `128` (`1000 0000` in Binary).

So basically 1 and 1 will be 1, everything else will be 0.

```
1000 0010 -> First Byte
1000 0000 -> Our Masking Byte => 128 in Decimal
---------
1000 0000 -> Resulting Byte => 128 in Decimal (Fin bit set)
```

Another Example Fin bit not set and Text Data.

```
0000 0001 -> First Byte
1000 0000 -> Our Masking Byte -> 128 in Decimal
---------
0000 0000 -> Resulting Byte => 0 in Decimal (Fin bit not set)
```

*Example: Getting OpCode (OpCode tells you what this frame is used for)*

The OpCode can be gathered from the first 4 bits of the first byte. Pretend the FIN bit is set and the OpCode is Text.

```
1000 0001 -> First Byte
0000 1111 -> Our Masking Byte => 15 in Decimal
---------
0000 0001 -> Resulting Byte => 1 in Decimal (Text OpCode)
```

Comment: I know that your answer is correct.  But I'm having trouble wrapping my head around exactly *why* it is correct.  In the diagram above, the FIN bit is labeled as bit 0, the least significant, in the first byte.  However, you access it as though it were the *most* significant bit in the first byte.  
The same question applies to pulling the opcode out of the second nibble.  As per the diagram, this should be bits 4-7.  However, your mask grabs bits 0-3.  
Why do you use bit operations that seem to be the opposite of what the diagram specifies?

Comment: Any idea how to encode these frame bits in the websocket client while sending data to the websocket server? I am using ws npm module

Comment: @ShaikSyedAli node has already a good Websocket implementation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket